# Not able see test cases in Text Explorer for the .net core 2 based Test project

Tags: nunit, visual-studio-2017, nsubstitute, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I have created a test project based on `.Net Core 2` and wrote some `NUnit` test cases. After installing necessary `NuGet` packages i.e. `NUnit3TestAdapter`, I was able to see all test cases in "Test Explorer" and able to execute those. Now, when I looked into the project directory, I found that it's creating "obj" folder and some json files in it. So I tried to change the path of "obj" folder by modifying ".csproj" file. I provided some different path in the parameter "BaseIntermediateOutputPath" and that way, I was able to get rid of "obj" folder. The reason for providing different path was, I wanted to keep json files separate from source code.
However, after modifying that I am not able to see or execute any test cases from Test Explorer.
Is this a Microsoft bug?
Is any packages having dependency on "obj" folder?

P.S.
I am using "NUnit" and "NSubstitute" packages for my test project.

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>..\..\build\$(Configuration)\UnitTests\</OutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>..\..\work\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Castle.Core" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSubstitute" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.8.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UtilityLibrary\UtilityLibrary.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: The obj folder is used in the compilation process. There is absolutely no reason to move it, and as you have seen it may cause problems with the tooling. As a doctor, I must give you my official opinion that you should stop hitting yourself in the head with a hammer.

Comment: Hi Will,
Actually I am able to provide "BaseIntermediateOutputPath" for normal project but not for test project. Does it have any dependency on NuGet package which I am using.
In my organization, it's practice to keep related files in separate directory so I want to keep all obj related files in separate directory rather than keeping "obj" folder in source directory.

Answer (score 1):

When .NET Core projects build, they do not copy all referenced files into the bin folder. When you add `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` to your test project, one of the things it does is add an `AssemblyResolve` [event handler](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/blob/b91bd795e53806da15ebc6ad6ebd4cc22e710d72/src/Microsoft.TestPlatform.Common/Utilities/AssemblyResolver.cs#L65) which loads other dependent assemblies from a list of `searchDirectories`.

`BaseIntermediateOutputPath` not working was [reported against the VSTest project](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/828) and is an issue with MSBuild. The [workaround is noted in the dotnet sdk repository](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/980#issuecomment-285957284). From that, you need to use `Sdk` imports in your `csproj` instead of the `Sdk` attribute on the `Project` element.

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>obj\XXX\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>    
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  <!-- Body of project -->

  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Hello Rob,
This solution also I tried but seems like didn't work for me.
I am adding my csproj file in original question.

Comment: You still have the SDK attribute on the project element, first line. Did you try removing that?

Comment: Gotcha, removing SDK attribute from project worked.
Thanks for pointing out that.